# SSAS Tabular incorrect syntax but it is correct

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax, sql-server-data-tools, ssas-tabular

I am trying to use the IN function is analysis services tabular, but it is returning me an error. I tried the same on my co-worker's machine and it is working perfectly. I have already uninstalled my data tools 2017 and 2015 and installed again. Now I have only SSDT 2015 and having this problem.

```
TestMeasureIN:= 
CALCULATE(
COUNTROWS(DimDate),
DimDate[MonthName] IN {"may", "july"}
)
```

**SEMANTIC ERROR: THE SYNTAX FOR 'IN' IS INCORRECT**

Comment: "In" syntax in DAX was introduced in November 2016. What's your co-worker SSDT version?

Comment: Yep. The `IN` syntax is newer. SQLBI has a good [article](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/the-in-operator-in-dax/) about this.

Comment: But he can use IN and I am not and we are both using SSDT 2015. Mine is a more recent version and his version is older

Answer (score 3):

The `IN` function won't be available for versions of SSAS prior to 2017, so SSDT 2015 won't have this.  You can rewrite this using `CONTAINS` as follows.  Also, I'm guessing that `TestMeasureIN` is in your fact table as opposed to `DimDate`?  If so, change `COUNTROWS` to the fact table to count the rows for the given months.

```
TestMeasureIN:= 
        CALCULATE (
            COUNTROWS ( FactTableName),
            FILTER (
                ALL ( DimDate[MonthName]),
                CONTAINS (
                    DATATABLE ( "MonthName", STRING, { { "may", "july"} } ),
                    [MonthName], DimDate[MonthName]
                )
            )
        )
```